# Jenkins job with multiple repositories and specific branches build on push to those branches

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

Updating a jenkins instances, so upgrading to pipelines from a mix of multiple SCM plugin and upstream/downstream jobs.

There are two repositories with multiple branches, for each build job there is a unique branch combination.  In the workspace for the job, one repo should be checked out as the root folder, and the other should be checked out as a folder inside the root folder.  Example:

- job1 uses repo2:branch-master and is dependent on repo1:branch-4.2
- job2 uses repo2:branch-stage and is dependent on repo1:branch-4.3
- job3 uses repo2:branch-redesign and is dependent on repo1:branch-4.2

The issue, how does a jenkins job poll for specific (differently named) branches from multiple repositories, AKA how does the jenkins job1 only build when a change is pushed to either repo2:branch-master or repo1:branch-4.2